# java generics <T extends Number>

Tags: java, generics

I have this code:

```
public class Test<T extends Number>{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       Test<Short> test = new Test(Short.class);
       System.out.println(test.get());
   }
   private Class<T> clazz;
   public Test(Class<T> clazz){
      this.clazz=clazz;
   }
   public T get(){
      if(clazz == Short.class)
          return new Short(13); //type missmatch cannot convert from Short to T
      else return null;
   }
}
```

but it does not compile... Any Idea how I repair this?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot construct a `Short` with an `int` (there is no such constructor), and you could cast to `T` like

```
public T get() {
    if (clazz == Short.class)
        return (T) Short.valueOf((short) 13);
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: FYI, you'll get an **unchecked cast** warning.

Answer (score 0):

Because your return type is generic `T` not Short. so you will get type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of construction in your code looks more suitable for a non-generics implementation:

Instead of:

```
public T get() {
```

Declare it as:

```
public Number get () {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public T get() {
    if (clazz == Short.class) {
        Short s = 13;
        return (T) s;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You think a piece of code without any further explanation makes up a good answer?

Comment: Yes, because it will fulfill the requirement if PO. :)

Comment: Well, according to the standards of this very site ... there is more to a **good** answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer ) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you write below, compiler will complain

```
 Short s = new Short(13); //The constructor Short(int) is undefined
```

workaround

```
Short s = new Short((short) 13);
```

your case

```
 return (T) new Short((short) 13);
```